# Precision of Metropolis Monte Carlo sampling of a PDF

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling, monte-carlo

I want to sample from the probability distribution function (PDF)

$$p(t)=3e^{-t}\big[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-8t}\cos({40t})\big]$$

for $0<t<1$. The function looks like this:

[PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbPlC.png)

The PDF can not be analytically inverted, so I tried to use Metropolis Monte Carlo sampling with the following python code:

```
pdf = lambda t: 3*np.exp(-t)*(0.5+0.5*np.exp(-8*t)*np.cos(40*t))
lw  = 0
up  = 1
sig = 0.1
ini_t   = 0.01
new_t   = ini_t
samples = []
for i in range(100000):
    cand_t = scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs((lw-new_t)/sig, (up-new_t)/sig, loc=new_t, scale=sig)
    if np.random.uniform(0, 1) < pdf(cand_t)/pdf(new_t):
        new_t = cand_t
    samples.append(new_t)
burn_in = 10000
samples = np.array(samples[burn_in:])
```

The result looks like the green plot of the following image:

[Simulated PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZleI9.png)

As it is obvious, the performance of sampling is rather poor. How can I improve it?

Comment: Your pdf is not a pdf.  Its integral from $0$ to $1$ is only about $0.6559173858$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yeah. But that is just scaling. The main problem is the functionality.

Comment: Recheck your plot of P. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+1.5+exp%28-x%29+%28+1%2Bexp%28-8x%29+cos%2840x%29%29+from+0+to+1) shows that the integral of P(t) from 0 to 1 is about 0.96, and it's plot of the function is decently close to what your simulation results show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program looks fine except that there's too much indentation before `samples.append(new_t)`. That line shouldn't be conditional on the `if` statement; a sample is generated regardless of whether you accept or reject.

By the way, you're using ”performance“ in an unorthodox way. In this context it's usually used to mean speed; judging from the image, your problem rather seems to be correctness.

Comment: ... one of the downsides in a language where whitespace has semantic significance ...

Comment: @joriki Thanks. I applied your comments. Now that is so much better. How can I improve it, especially at the area close to zero?